# iterate through all combinations of cards

Tags: java

I'm creating a card game and would like to iterate through all possible combinations of card.

For example (Ace of Hearts, Two of Hearts), (Ace of Hearts, Two of Spades), (Ace of Hearts, Two of Clubs).... etc

I'm doing this in java

Currently I have this:

to start with I have

```
List<Card> deckOfCards = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

which is a deck containing all Cards. Then I create a

```
Queue<Card> deckOfCardsWithoutDuplicates = new LinkedList<Card>();
        deckOfCardsWithoutDuplicates = deckOfCards;
```

Now I want to iterate through all of the cards without duplicates.

```
        for (Card c : deckOfCards) {

            deckOfCardsWithoutDuplicates.remove(c);
            for (Card c1 : deckOfCardsWithoutDuplicates) {

//something here irrelevant

            }
            deckOfCardsWithoutDuplicates.add(c);
        }
```

However I get a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` . Can anyone give me some hints on how to do this better?

Comment: just take a copy of the list. iterate through the main list with the outer loop. iterate through the copy list with the inner loop. you can't do add-remove operations on a list that is being iterated with `for`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern Singleton and Builder come in your help.

The Singleton is used to Suite and Value of Cards.

Suite example:

```
public class Suit {
  private String suit;
  private Suit(String name) {suit = name;}
  public String toString() {return suit;}
  public final static Suit CLUBS = new Suit("clubs");
  public final static Suit DIAMONDS = new Suit("diamonds");
  public final static Suit HEARTS = new Suit("hearts");
  public final static Suit SPADES = new Suit("spades");
}
```

Same thing is with the value class, the Card class should be a Singleton too but they are so much and should be a combination of other two Singleton (Suite and Value):

```
public class Card {
  private Suit s;
  private Value v;
  protected Card() {}
  protected Card(Suit s, Value v) {
    this.s = s;
    this.v = v;
  }
}
```

The unique Card si guarantee from a builder of Cards (Using Builder Pattern):

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
public class CardBuilder extends Card {
   private Hashtable<String,Card> _cards = new Hashtable<String,Card>();
   public Card getCard(Suit s, Value v) {
     String key = s.toString() + v.toString();
     Card result = _cards.get(key);
     if (result == null) {
         result = new Card(s,v);
         _cards.put(key,result);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

And now you have all you need the hashtable take a trace of cards that you use and don't use it againt. Now there is main that you can check your implementation in hi level check:

```
public class Game {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
     CardBuilder cb = new CardBuilder();
     Card c1 = cb.getCard(Suit.HEARTS, Value.JACK);
     Card c2 = cb.getCard(Suit.HEARTS, Value.JACK);
   if (c1 == c2) System.out.println("Ok!!!");
   else System.out.println("Something wrong in you implementation!");
 }
}
```

I hope that this example can help in your implementation of game play :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're trying to remove from a list that you're looping through.

To remove from a list that you're looping through, you need to use an [iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **Iterator** instead of **foreach** loop

```
Iterator<Card> iter = deckOfCards.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
   //your logic here
}
```

When you are using **foreach** loop, you are using **iterator implicitly**.

**ConcurrentModificationException** occurs when the collection is modified by "simultaneously" with the passage of an iterator over a collection by any means, except for the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Your naming seems to indicate that you think you have two lists, one initially being a copy of the other but being modified while traversing the original.  But they are actually the same list, and as noted in other answers, you'll get this exception when you modify the list you're looping through.

If you change your code so that they're really separate lists, the issue you've shown won't happen.

Change

```
Queue<Card> deckOfCardsWithoutDuplicates = new LinkedList<Card>();
deckOfCardsWithoutDuplicates = deckOfCards;
```

to

```
Queue<Card> deckOfCardsWithoutDuplicates = new LinkedList<Card>(deckOfCards);
```

and you'll be able to modify `deckOfCardsWithoutDuplicates` while looping through `deckOfCards`.